# create new csv file to local drive

Tags: python

finalfaultdata = pd.read_csv('FinalFaultData.csv')

passedmaster = pd.read_csv('PASSEDMASTER.csv')

A = pd.concat([finalfaultdata,passedmaster])

print(A)

with open ('output.csv', 'w') as output:

```
writer = csv.writer(output)

writer.writerows(A)
```

Comment: Its just a simple syntax error. try this:
pd.concat([finalfaultdata,passedmaster])

Answer (score 0):

As you are using Pandas, you can merge the dataframe:

`finalfaultdata = finalfaultdata.merge(passedmaster)`

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html

To save it as a CSV you can simply use:

`finalfaultdata.to_csv('finalfaultdata.csv')`

Comment: how to download this merge file as new csv file in text

Comment: I updated the answer with to_csv method